# Efficient comparison of tuple with list

Tags: python, loops, iterator, tuples, list-comparison

I have a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a string representation of xyz coordinates. I need to compare the first and second values of the tuples to another set of values in a dictionary(to determine if the first item in the tuple is the start point or end point)

i.e.

```
tuple_list = [('0.1, 0.5, 2.0', '3.0, 5.0, 6.0'), ('0.0, 0.6, 2.0', '4.0, 5.0, 6.0')]

vertex_dict = {'0': '3.0, 5.0, 6.0', '1': '0.0, 0.6, 2.0'}
```

if the first item in the tuple matches the vertex list, I want to indicate that it is the "start" point, while the second item in the tuple is the "end" point.

Currently I'm accomplishing this with the following code:

```
pt_line_dict = {}
for key, value in vertex_dict:
    for i, j in tuple_list:
        if i == value:
            pt_line_dict[key] = (i, j)
        elif j == value:
            pt_line_dict[key] = (j, i)
        else:
            pass

Output:
pt_line_dict = {'0': ('3.0, 5.0, 6.0', '0.1, 0.5, 2.0'), '1': ('0.0, 0.6, 2.0', '4.0, 5.0, 6.0')}
```

There is no chance of having duplicate values between tuples, and the vertex dictionary is also unique (no repeats of key values).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this that avoids looping over all values in tuple list? I think a generator might be a way of doing this...

Comment: what would be the desired output for the example you posted?

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: your initial approach is not so bad

Answer (score 0):

According to *"There is no chance of having duplicate values between tuples, and the vertex dictionary is also unique"* and you need *a more efficient way of doing this that avoids looping over **all** values in tuple list* - I can only suggest the solution which avoids redundant inner loop iterations:

```
pt_line_dict = {}

for k,v in vertex_dict.items():
    for t in tuple_list:
        if v in t:
            idx = t.index(v)
            pt_line_dict[k] = (t[idx], t[int(not idx)])
            break

print(pt_line_dict)
```

The output:

```
{'0': ('3.0, 5.0, 6.0', '0.1, 0.5, 2.0'), '1': ('0.0, 0.6, 2.0', '4.0, 5.0, 6.0')}
```